# Can't retrieve from sql database and set value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have these tables in a mysql database:

**answer_det:**

[image]

**question:**

[image]

I want to select 4 answers for one question that belongs to a specific project. Every question has an id(qid) and every project has an id(pid). For example, I want to select every answer that belongs to pid=2 qid=3. Then I want to store the retrieved values(answers) into input text fields. That is the information I want to retrieve from the "answer_det"-table.

From the "question"-table, I want to retrieve the question_link for the same "pid" and

```html
<?php
    
if (!empty($error_msg)) {
    echo $error_msg;
}

$qid1 = $_POST['qid'];
                    
$retrieve ="SELECT answer FROM answer_det AS answer1 WHERE pid = '" . $_SESSION['pid'] . "' AND qid ='$qid1' AND aid'1'";
$retrieve .="SELECT answer FROM answer_det AS answer2 WHERE pid = '" . $_SESSION['pid'] . "' AND qid ='$qid1' AND aid'2'";
$retrieve .="SELECT answer FROM answer_det AS answer3 WHERE pid = '" . $_SESSION['pid'] . "' AND qid ='$qid1' AND aid'3'";
$retrieve .="SELECT answer FROM answer_det AS answer4 WHERE pid = '" . $_SESSION['pid'] . "' AND qid ='$qid1' AND aid'4'";

$retrieve .="SELECT question_link FROM question WHERE pid = '" . $_SESSION['pid'] . "' AND qid ='$qid1'";
               
$result = $mysqli->multi_query($retrieve);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {

        echo "
            <form action='insertdilemma.php' method='post'><br>

        <h2>Dilemma</h2>

        <div>Video link:<br><textarea rows='1' cols='40' name='videolink1'>". $row["question_link"]. "</textarea></div>
            
            Svar 1: <input type='text' name='ans1' value='". $row["answer1"]. "'>
            Svar 2: <input type='text' name='ans1' value='". $row["answer2"]. "'>
            Svar 3: <input type='text' name='ans1' value='". $row["answer3"]. "'>
            Svar 4: <input type='text' name='ans1' value='". $row["answer4"]. "'>

<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Create'>   
</form>
";
    }}
    
else {
    echo "Wrong info.";
}

mysqli_close($mysqli);
  
?>
```

I get this error:
**Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\wildfire\editdilemma.php on line 77**

Which is this line:
**if ($result->num_rows > 0) {**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should check the value of `result` after `$result = $mysqli->multi_query($retrieve);`

This call might have failed, returning `FALSE`, which would explain the error message you get.

As an aside, why are you running 4 queries instead of combining conditions in a single query?

Comment: @Richard St-Cyr how can I do that to see the explanation of the error message? I run 4 queries because all answers have specific answer id(aid). I couldn't find any way to compine it, but I think that this should work.

Comment: You can return the `aid` for each answer in the results, and then this should return all of the answers for the current `$_SESSION['pid']` and `$qid1`

Comment: try this `$retrieve ="SELECT answer FROM answer_det AS answer1 WHERE pid = '" . $_SESSION['pid'] . "' AND qid ='$qid1' AND aid = '1'"` for every query. It says non-object error because nothing is present in your $result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to first fix the errors by using a simple query like:

```
$retrieve ="SELECT aid, answer FROM answer_det WHERE pid = '" . $_SESSION['pid'] . "' AND qid ='$qid1'";
```

You will then have each answer as the result, so you have to change your while loop to properly output the results in HTML.

Comment: Well like I said, it will give you all of the answers (1-4) for the current question you just need to loop through them differently, you were doing it wrong to begin with...